# Winform Crystal reports using local files

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports

I have an application which is connected to a game server.
Each time it receives an item, it shows this as "User  gave you item  at . Transaction ID# 1kl9d4ns."

I would like to store this data in some sort of lical database file (not using an SQL server), and then be able to generate a report (crystal report or any other reporting module). Preferably exportable to PDF files.

Is this at all possible?
All examples I find are using some sort of database connection.
Could anyone please point me in the direction of a good tutorial that works with local files instead of connecting to an SQL server?

Thanks

Comment: What about XML? You can manage and store it locally, and CR can use it as a data source.

Comment: which local database? You'll always have the option to "push" a dataset to a crystal report if CR is unable to connect to your source.

Comment: @JeffreyWieder Hmm, so CR can read and create the report from an XML file? Then it's easy to make, thanks :)

Comment: @dotjoe With "local database", I mean a locally stored database file. Ie. Not connecting to a SQL server (locally installed or remote)

Comment: You still have to create the report definition in CR with an XML data source, but you can then run it against your file anytime after that.

Comment: Yes, but which vendor? SQLite? Just wondering because CR might be able to connect to the file.